# K-Lipschitz for the Wasserstein GANs

Tags: generative-models, wasserstein

I am trying to follow this blog for Wasserstein loss for Generative Adversarial Networks:
[From GAN to WGAN](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2017/08/20/from-GAN-to-WGAN.html).

Actually, I am trying to follow the logic behind the K-Lipschitz continuity. This post in order to describe it, make use of a function a $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is K-Lipschitz if:

$$|f(x_{1}) - f(x_{2})| \leq K|x_{1}- x_{2}|,$$ with $x_{1}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ to be scalars.

How this function can be transformed for the needs of GANs where the input is not a scalar. How K-Lipschitz is transformed in multiple dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of K-Lipschitz continuity is not only for scalar-valued inputs. For example, a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ is K-Lipschitz if: $|f(u)-f(v)| \leq K \|v-u\|$ $\forall v, u \in \mathbb{R}^3$. You can consider the norm on the right hand side to be the $l2-$norm, i.e. $\|u-v\| = \sqrt{(u_x-v_x)^2 + (u_y - v_y)^2 + (u_z-v_z)^2}$, where $u_x, u_y, u_z$ are the, $x-$, $y-$, $z-$ components of $u$.

Comment: Oooh ok yeah cool. For some reason, I missed that the norm is also a scalar.